# Exporting Ag-Grid to PDF using angular 7

Tags: angular, pdf, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Angular 7 and I am attempting to export ag-grid to pdf. I know how to export to csv and excel. The problem is that when I am trying to export to pdf, the only thing I can find in the documentation is how to print.

Anyone has had any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, PDF export is not a feature of ag-grid.
You're going to have to implement it yourself.
Depending on you environment, it may be easiest to do this on the server side.

Comment: Ended up using print functionality

Comment: Hi Can you elaborate more on this ?

Answer (score 0):

pdfMake integrates well with ag-Grid for PDF exports. It requires you to generate a 2D array containing all the columns and rows values to be printed as a PDF table.

```
function getColumnsToExport() {
    let columnsToExport = [];

    agGridColumnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns().forEach(col => {
      let pdfExportOptions = getPdfExportOptions(col.getColId());
      if (pdfExportOptions && pdfExportOptions.skipColumn) {
        return;
      }
      let headerCell = createHeaderCell(col);
      columnsToExport.push(headerCell);
    });

    return columnsToExport;
  }

  function getRowsToExport(columnsToExport) {
    let rowsToExport = [];

    agGridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(node => {
      if (PDF_SELECTED_ROWS_ONLY && !node.isSelected()) {
        return;
      }
      let rowToExport = columnsToExport.map(({ colId }) => {
        let cellValue = agGridApi.getValue(colId, node);
        let tableCell = createTableCell(cellValue, colId);
        return tableCell;
      });
      rowsToExport.push(rowToExport);
    });

    return rowsToExport;
  }
```

You can even set styling options so that the exported table looks just like ag-Grid

```
PDF_HEADER_COLOR = "#f8f8f8";
PDF_INNER_BORDER_COLOR = "#dde2eb";
PDF_OUTER_BORDER_COLOR = "#babfc7";
PDF_HEADER_HEIGHT = 25;
PDF_ROW_HEIGHT = 15;
PDF_ODD_BKG_COLOR = "#fcfcfc";
PDF_EVEN_BKG_COLOR = "#ffffff";

const heights = rowIndex =>
      rowIndex < headerRows ? PDF_HEADER_HEIGHT : PDF_ROW_HEIGHT;

    const fillColor = (rowIndex, node, columnIndex) => {
      if (rowIndex < node.table.headerRows) {
        return PDF_HEADER_COLOR;
      }
      return rowIndex % 2 === 0 ? PDF_ODD_BKG_COLOR : PDF_EVEN_BKG_COLOR;
    };

    const hLineWidth = (i, node) =>
      i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length ? 1 : 1;

    const vLineWidth = (i, node) =>
      i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length ? 1 : 0;

    const hLineColor = (i, node) =>
      i === 0 || i === node.table.body.length
        ? PDF_OUTER_BORDER_COLOR
        : PDF_INNER_BORDER_COLOR;

    const vLineColor = (i, node) =>
      i === 0 || i === node.table.widths.length
        ? PDF_OUTER_BORDER_COLOR
        : PDF_INNER_BORDER_COLOR;
```

See:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-pdf-make?file=src%2Findex.html